# How to calculate the values with using TextWatcher

Tags: android, if-statement, textwatcher

I want to calculate totals of T,T2,T3,T4 which i given in calculate method.

how to calculate this values using TextWatcher

and if i don't put any value in calculate 3 () method. how can i store 0 value in T3.

for example

```
T= 2*3*1/144*2 = 0.08333
T2=2*3*1/144*2 = 0.08333
T3= if no any num of value put =0
T4=2*3*1/144*2 = 0.08333
fullTotal = 0.2499

I want this type of output. please help me

    @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Edtinch1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch1);
            Edtinch2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch2);
            Edtfeet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet);
            Edtquan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qunt);
            Totaltxt1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total1);
            Edtquan.addTextChangedListener(this);

            Edtinch21 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch21);
            Edtinch22 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch22);
            Edtfeet2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet2);
            Edtquan2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qunt2);
            Totaltxt2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total2);
            Edtquan2.addTextChangedListener(this);

            Edtinch31 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch31);
            Edtinch32 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inch32);
            Edtfeet3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feet3);
            Edtquan3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qunt3);
            Totaltxt3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.total3);
            Edtquan3.addTextChangedListener(this);


            fulltotal1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fulltotal);

            btnsnap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncapture);
            btnsnap.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

            public void calculate(){
                //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
                inch11 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch1.getText().toString());
                inch12 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch2.getText().toString());
                feet11 = Double.parseDouble(Edtfeet.getText().toString());
                quan11 = Double.parseDouble(Edtquan.getText().toString());
                //do the calculation
                Double calculated1 = (inch11*inch12)*(feet11)/144*(quan11);
                //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
                T= calculated1.toString();
                Totaltxt1.setText(T);

                } 


            public void calculate2(){
                //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
                inch21 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch21.getText().toString());
                inch22 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch22.getText().toString());
                feet2 = Double.parseDouble(Edtfeet2.getText().toString());
                quan2 = Double.parseDouble(Edtquan2.getText().toString());
                //do the calculation
                Double calculated2 = (inch21*inch22)*(feet2)/144*(quan2);
                //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
                T2= calculated2.toString();
                Totaltxt2.setText(T2);

                }

            public void calculate3(){
                //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
                inch31 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch31.getText().toString());
                inch32 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch32.getText().toString());
                feet3 = Double.parseDouble(Edtfeet3.getText().toString());
                quan3 = Double.parseDouble(Edtquan3.getText().toString());
                //do the calculation
                Double calculated3 = (inch31*inch32)*(feet3)/144*(quan3);
                //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
                T3= calculated3.toString();
                Totaltxt3.setText(T3);

                }

            public void calculate4(){
                //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
                inch41 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch41.getText().toString());
                inch42 = Double.parseDouble(Edtinch42.getText().toString());
                feet4 = Double.parseDouble(Edtfeet4.getText().toString());
                quan4 = Double.parseDouble(Edtquan4.getText().toString());
                //do the calculation
                Double calculated4 = (inch41*inch42)*(feet4)/144*(quan4);
                //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
                T4= calculated4.toString();
                Totaltxt4.setText(T4);

                }

            public void fullcalculate()
            {


                }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                     if (Edtinch1.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch1.setError("Input Inch");
                         }

                        else if (Edtinch2.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch2.setError("Input Inch");
                         }
                        else if (Edtfeet.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtfeet.setError("Input feet");
                         }
                        else if (Edtquan.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                            Edtquan.setError("Input Quantity");
                         }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Edtquan.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
                            {
                                calculate();
                            }
                         }



                     if (Edtinch21.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch21.setError("Input Inch");
                         }

                        else if (Edtinch22.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch22.setError("Input Inch");
                         }
                        else if (Edtfeet2.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtfeet2.setError("Input feet");
                         }
                        else if (Edtquan2.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                            Edtquan2.setError("Input Quantity");
                         }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Edtquan2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
                            {
                                calculate2();
                            }
                         }

                     if (Edtinch31.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch31.setError("Input Inch");
                         }

                        else if (Edtinch32.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch32.setError("Input Inch");
                         }
                        else if (Edtfeet3.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtfeet3.setError("Input feet");
                         }
                        else if (Edtquan3.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                            Edtquan3.setError("Input Quantity");
                         }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Edtquan3.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
                            {
                                calculate3();
                            }
                         }

                     if (Edtinch41.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch41.setError("Input Inch");
                         }

                        else if (Edtinch42.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtinch42.setError("Input Inch");
                         }enter code here
                        else if (Edtfeet4.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
                        {
                            Edtfeet4.setError("Input feet");
                         }
                        else if (Edtquan4.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                            Edtquan4.setError("Input Quantity");
                         }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Edtquan4.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
                            {
                                calculate4();
                            }
                         }

                        }
```

Comment: The relevant code will get you a quicker and better response.

Comment: @Rohit5k2:i have uploaded it Please help me

Comment: @rfornal :i have uploaded it, Plz help me

Comment: Why are you even using TextWatcher here?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : Actually i have used multiple Edittext in this app and i want output in Edittext without using any button.